# Why doesn't the number of shares in my miner match the number of shares reported by my pool?

Tags: mining-pools, mining-pool-shares, logging

It was my understanding that I have found a share, when the miner reports `accepted:...(yay)`.

However, the number of shares I'm being credited with in my pool is much lower than the number in the miner.

I'm talking about total shares as I have always used the same pool, and I haven't reset the miner so far. So, both should refer to the same frame of time.

Why doesn't the number of shares in my miner match the number of shares reported by my pool?

Comment: If you're using P2Pool, the [following Q/A](http://bit.ly/1hFUBWw) might be helpful: "Q: Why does my miner say it has found a lot of shares but p2pool say I have only found a few?!
A: The real P2Pool difficulty is hundreds of times higher than on normal pools, but p2pool essentially lies to your miner and tells it to work on relatively easy shares so that it submits shares every few seconds instead of every few hours. P2Pool then ignores any submitted shares that don't match the real share difficulty. By doing this, P2Pool can more accurately report your local hash rate and you can see if..."

Comment: Or another pool might do something similar. What pool and software are you using?

Comment: I'm using DEDICATEDPOOL mining 42Coin. Yeah your answer corresponds with my problems though, thanks a lot, I was just worried that I'm loosing coins because I'm a newbie.

Comment: @TimS. You really should post this as an answer.

Comment: @Murch I was unsure, but yeah, I've posted it as an answer. Might not be perfectly right, but probably helps...

Comment: Well, it seems to be a likely explanation and the asker stated that it fits his problem – that's why I suggested you post it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that your pool is doing something [similar to P2Pool](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/P2Pool#Frequently_Asked_Questions):

> **Q:** Why does my miner say it has found a lot of shares but p2pool say I
>   have only found a few?!
>   **A:** The real P2Pool difficulty is hundreds of
>   times higher than on normal pools, but p2pool essentially lies to your
>   miner and tells it to work on relatively easy shares so that it
>   submits shares every few seconds instead of every few hours. P2Pool
>   then ignores any submitted shares that don't match the real share
>   difficulty. By doing this, P2Pool can more accurately report your
>   local hash rate and you can see if you are having problems with too
>   many stale shares quickly